# How to check docker instance is running in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, docker

Having `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                    NAMES

56489a32cb8c        83132b61eccf                  "bash"                   41 hours ago        Exited (0) 41 hours ago                            naughty_jang
4b4933b40175        83119b65eccf                  "bash"                   41 hours ago        Exited (0) 41 hours ago                            suspicious_mcnulty
3149e612f9f8        83119b6143cf                  "sh"                     43 hours ago        Exited (0) 41 hours ago                            thirsty_mestorf
```

I want to match the `STATUS` and the `NAMES` colums to check which is the instance status, so columns 5 and 7 starting from columns index `1`.

Supposed to have tab separated values I do

```
docker ps -a | awk -FS $'\t' '{print $5,$7}'
```

or

```
docker ps -a | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {print $5,$7}'
```

but this will not work, while keeping the default whitespace char as `FS`

```
docker ps -a | awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "}; {print $5,$7}'
```

So I have tried to match one column at time like

```
awk -F$" " -v COLT=$1 '
        NR==1 {
                for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                        if ($i==COLT) {
                                title=i;
                        }
                }
        }
        NR>1 {
                if (i=title) {
                        print $i
                }
        }
'
```

Supposed to have this in a script you do

```
docker ps -a | ./status.sh NAMES
```

but due to the bad tabbed spaces matching this will not work.
Problem here is that the output of `docker ps -a` has spaces, not tabs, so a variable number of spaces, so I should use a specific regex as `FS` field separators as described [here](https://docs.freebsd.org/info/gawk/gawk.info.Field_Separators.html), but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: You don't need to specify the tab, just get to the column you want.

Comment: `NAMES` can ben random generated or fixed, so I want to match all, while `STATUS` column is like `[a-Z]+ (\d) (\d\d hours ago)` (just to simplify...)` or `Created`, etc.

Comment: @loretoparisi: Can I ask your actual expected output for your input? The above comments are misleading

Comment: @Inian yes this is the values of colums `NAMES` and `STATUS` for each row, showed in question i.e output of `docker ps -a`.

Comment: If you just want the status of a specific container you can use `docker inspect -f "{{.State.Status}}" container-name`

Comment: @Henry thank you just get answered below, didn't know about this formatting option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `docker ps --format "{{.ID}} {{.Command}} {{.Status}}"` would be easier to parse, as it would only have three columns.

With [formatting](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#/formatting), you can only display the bare minimum information you need, and have the separator you want between each column.

The [OP loretoparisi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758836/loretoparisi) recommends [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210470/how-to-check-docker-instance-is-running-in-bash/41210542?noredirect=1#comment69619897_41210542):

```
docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}\t\"{{.Status}}\"\t{{.Names}}" | cut -f2 -d$'\t'
```

> to get col 2, or you could do:

```
docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}\t\"{{.Status}}\"\t{{.Names}}" | awk -F$"\t" '{printf "%s|%s|%s\n", $1, $2, $3}'
```

> to rule them all!

Comment: so like this `docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}\t\"{{.Status}}\"\t{{.Names}}"` ?

Comment: @loretoparisi ye, if you want to cut with a tab: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35370/7490

Comment: yes! that is like: `docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}\t\"{{.Status}}\"\t{{.Names}}" | cut -f2 -d$'\t'` to get col 2, or you could do `docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}\t\"{{.Status}}\"\t{{.Names}}" | awk -F$"\t" '{printf "%s|%s|%s\n", $1, $2, $3}'` to rule them all!

Comment: @loretoparisi nicely done. I have included your comments in the answer for more visibility.